# Specific regex in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to build a regular expression which should apply for the following:

(Valid for 1 - 4 Blocks (seperated with "/") which contain exactly 4 characters that are HEX numbers)

```
Valid example 1: 3F00 / FA41 / FA12 / B12F
Valid example 2: 4F0T
Valid example 3: FFFF / FF21

Invalid example 1: 34BF /
Invalid example 2: 45FB2
Invalid example 3: 4B5S / BD45 BA56
Invalid example 4: FF02/B200
...
```

I just can't figure it out. Here's what I have for now:

```
1: ([0-9A-F]{4})( \/ \1){1,3}|[0-9A-F]{4}
2: [0-9A-F]{4} \/ [0-9A-F]{4} \/ [0-9A-F]{4} \/ [0-9A-F]{4}|[0-9A-F]{4} \/ [0-9A-F]{4} \/ [0-9A-F]{4}|[0-9A-F]{4} \/ [0-9A-F]{4}|[0-9A-F]{4}
```

Second pretty ugly and both not working!

Comment: You second line is not valid

Comment: The 'T' in 4FOT isn't Hex either. :-)

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, fixed thanks

Comment: Is `3F00/FA41` (without spaces) valid?

Comment: Do you only want to validate if a line obeys the regex pattern, or do you also want to extract the matched 4-character words?

Comment: @Andrew That would be invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest

```
 ^[0-9A-F]{4}( \/ [0-9A-F]{4}){0,3}$
```

pattern:

```
 ^                      - string start
 [0-9A-F]{4}            - 4 hex digits
 ( \/ [0-9A-F]{4}){0,3} - up to 3 more 4 digits groups
 $                      - string end
```

Comment: This allows more than 4 blocks, which would be invalid

Comment: @Mr. Toast: if we want up to `4` blocks; `{,3}` should be used instead of `*`

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
^[\dA-F]{4}( \/ [\dA-F]{4}){0,3}$
```

It matches the first block (4 hex characters) and then optionally matches 0-3 subsequent blocks separated by `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work, if the input is given line by line:

```
^([0-9A-F]{4})( \/ [0-9A-F]{4}){0,3}$
```

Comment: Does not work if the blocks contain different characters:
FFFF / FFFF = valid;
2222 / 1111 = invalid

Comment: Remove the back reference, then it should work. Sorry forgot to remove that.